# STM32 programming tips and questions

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, cortex-m

I could not find any good document on internet about STM32 programming. STM's own documents do not explain anything more than register functions. I will greatly appreciate if anyone can explain my following questions?

1. I noticed that in all example programs that STM provides, local variables for main() are always defined outside of the main() function (with occasional use of static keyword). Is there any reason for that? Should I follow a similar practice? Should I avoid using local variables inside the main?
2. I have a gloabal variable which is updated within the clock interrupt handle. I am using the same variable inside another function as a loop condition. Don't I need to access this variable using some form of atomic read operation? How can I know that a clock interrupt does not change its value in the middle of the function execution? Should I need to cancel clock interrupt everytime I need to use this variable inside a function? (However, this seems extremely ineffective to me as I use it as loop condition. I believe there should be better ways of doing it).
3. Keil automatically inserts a startup code which is written in assembly (i.e. startup_stm32f4xx.s). This startup code has the following import statements:
       IMPORT  SystemInit
       IMPORT  __main
   .In "C", it makes sense. However, in C++ both main and system_init have different names (e.g. _*int*_main__void). How can this startup code can still work in C++ even without using "extern "C" " (I tried and it worked). How can the c++ linker (armcc --cpp) can associate these statements with the correct functions?

Comment: These questions are all pretty much unrelated.  Why not break them up into three different questions on stackoverflow so that if someone knows the answer to one of them but not all of them they can still provide advice to you?

Comment: @DavidGrayson, I agree. As a late-coming reader, I'd also rather they be separated, so I can find what I care about more efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use local or global variables, using local in embedded systems has a risk of your stack colliding with your data.  with globals you dont have that problem.  but this is true no matter where you are, embedded microcontroller, desktop, etc.

I would make a copy of the global in the foreground task that uses it.

```
unsigned int myglobal;

void fun ( void )
{
   unsigned int myg;

   myg=myglobal;
```

and then only use myg for the rest of the function.  Basically you are taking a snapshot and using the snapshot.  You would want to do the same thing if you are reading a register, if you want to do multiple things based on a sample of something take one sample of it and make decisions on that one sample, otherwise the item can change between samples.   If you are using one global to communicate back and forth to the interrupt handler, well I would use two variables one foreground to interrupt, the other interrupt to foreground.  yes, there are times where you need to carefully manage a shared resource like that, normally it has to do with times where you need to do more than one thing, for example if you had several items that all need to change as a group before the handler can see them change then you need to disable the interrupt handler until all the items have changed.   here again there is nothing special about embedded microcontrollers this is all basic stuff you would see on a desktop system with a full blown operating system.

Keil knows what they are doing if they support C++ then from a system level they have this worked out.  I dont use Keil I use gcc and llvm for microcontrollers like this one.

Edit:

Here is an example of what I am talking about

https://github.com/dwelch67/stm32vld/tree/master/stm32f4d/blinker05

stm32 using timer based interrupts, the interrupt handler modifies a variable shared with the foreground task.  The foreground task takes a single snapshot of the shared variable (per loop) and if need be uses the snapshot more than once in the loop rather than the shared variable which can change.  This is C not C++ I understand that, and I am using gcc and llvm not Keil.  (note llvm has known problems optimizing tight while loops, very old bug, dont know why they have no interest in fixing it, llvm works for this example).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I still have one question that bothers me. In OS based programming we assume that even a single assignment statement (i.e. a=b) is not atomic. Therefore, if "b" may change outside of the thread we have to use some kind of mutex. In embedded programming (with interrupt routines) isn't this the case? Even if "b" can be changed in an interrupt handler, can I assume that "a=b" is an atomic operation? Can i safely assume that "a" is equal to either the past or current value of "b"? (In OS based programming "a" could be anything unrelated with "b")

Comment: I disagree with dwelch's first sentence.  When you change a variable from being local to global, you are increasing your RAM usage because a global variable takes up RAM all the time, whereas a local variable only takes up RAM while the function is in scope, and even then it might be stored in a register instead of in RAM.  Since you are increasing your usage of RAM, this increases the chance of your stack colliding with your data (stack overflow).

Comment: @David-Grayson you have "control" over ram usage and it is very deterministic if you use globals, with locals that takes a lot more work and can vary with subtle changes.  if you are willing to do that analysis then go for it.  I certainly agree that locals give you "more ram" in the sense that you reuse it a lot and get a lot more variables available to your program, things like that.

Comment: @user460153 I should have mentioned that the shared variable might want to be declared as volatile to insure that the compiler actually reads it from ram (it all depends on what your code looks like).  When you read a=b and you insure that b is read from ram and not in a foreground register, AND the memory is something that can be read in a single transfer (32 bits or less, perhaps 64 bits but I doubt this thing has a 64 bit AXI/amba bus) THEN you are going to get a complete sample of that variable...

Comment: @user460531 yes it could be after or before the handler changes it.  Whether that is important or not depends on your system design.  If both users of the shared resource are doing read-modify-writes of that item then yes you do need both to use an atomic operation, and you would have to manage that through standard methods, turn off interrupts, locks, etc.  If one reads and the other read-modify-writes then you may not need to, depends on how your code works.  If it is a loop then you will catch the new value the next time around.

Comment: @user460531 get the TRM for the arm core they are using, the stm32 family has cortex-m3 and cortex-m4f and perhaps others.  Looking at a generic armv7m I see that for 8, 16, or 32 bits "The _Mem[] function performs single-copy atomic, aligned, little-endian memory accesses to the underlying physical memory array of bytes".  As with anything I would always make sure you are doing aligned accesses, that could affect your atomic concerns.

Comment: The cortex-m4f (stm32f, the one with a cortex-m4 and an fpu) is an AHB-lite 32 bit both on the instruction and data busses.

Comment: I would not be quite so cavalier about the use of global variables! Required reading: http://www.eetimes.com/discussion/break-point/4025723/A-pox-on-globals

Comment: If stack usage is a concern, you do not need to make variables have global scope just to get static allocation.

Comment: sure I see "local globals" local variables statically allocated and actual globals as the same, I understand the context usage thing, from an allocation standpoint they end up in the same place.

Answer (score 4):

**Question 1: Local variables**

The sample code provided by ST is not particularly efficient or elegant.  It gets the job done, but sometimes there are no good reasons for the things they do.

In general, you use always want your variables to have the smallest scope possible.  If you only use a variable in one function, define it inside that function.  Add the "static" keyword to local variables if and only if you need them to retain their value after the function is done.

In some embedded environments, like the PIC18 architecture with the C18 compiler, local variables are much more expensive (more program space, slower execution time) than global.  On the Cortex M3, that is not true, so you should feel free to use local variables.  Check the assembly listing and see for yourself.

**Question 2: Sharing variables between interrupts and the main loop**

People have written entire chapters explaining the answers to this group of questions.  Whenever you share a variable between the main loop and an interrupt, you should definitely use the `volatile` keywords on it.  Variables of 32 or fewer bits can be accessed atomically (unless they are misaligned).

If you need to access a larger variable, or two variables at the same time from the main loop, then you will have to disable the clock interrupt while you are accessing the variables.  If your interrupt does not require precise timing, this will not be a problem.  When you re-enable the interrupt, it will automatically fire if it needs to.

**Question 3: main function in C++**

I'm not sure.  You can use `arm-none-eabi-nm` (or whatever `nm` is called in your toolchain) on your object file to see what symbol name the C++ compiler assigns to `main()`.  I would bet that C++ compilers refrain from mangling the main function for this exact reason, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

STM's sample code is not an exemplar of good coding practice, it is merely intended to exemplify use of their standard peripheral library (assuming those are the examples you are talking about).  In some cases it may be that variables are declared external to `main()` because they are accessed from an interrupt context (shared memory).  There is also perhaps a possibility that it was done that way merely to allow the variables to be watched in the debugger from any context; but that is not a reason to copy the technique.  My opinion of STM's example code is that it is generally pretty poor even as example code, let alone from a software engineering point of view.

In this case your clock interrupt variable is atomic so long as it is 32bit or less so long as you are not using  *read-modify-write* semantics with multiple writers.  You can safely have one writer, and multiple readers regardless.  This is true for this particular platform, but not necessarily universally; the answer may be different for 8 or 16 bit systems, or for multi-core systems for example.  The variable should be declared `volatile` in any case.

I am using C++ on STM32 with Keil, and there is no problem.  I am not sure why you think that the C++ entry points are different, they are not here (Keil ARM-MDK v4.22a).  The start-up code calls `SystemInit()` which initialises the PLL and memory timing for example, then calls `__main()` which performs global static initialisation then calls C++ constructors for global static objects before calling `main()`.  If in doubt, step through the code in the debugger.  It is important to note that `__main()` is not the `main()` function you write for your application, it is a wrapper with different behaviour for C and C++, but which ultimately calls your `main()` function.